# How to Install JupyterHub in Remote server (Client Node) and use web browser from local machines to connect and run parallely?

Tags: jupyterhub

I am new to production environment server setup. I want to install JupyterHub in my company's remote server which we use as client Node, and allow developers to connect from their local machine though their web browser and build their code. Is there any documentation where I can refer to for installation and creating Login IDs for developers to connect from their browser and also how to allocate resources to each developer?

The Client node has 256 GB of ram, while there maybe up to 30 parallel users running their data analysis/machine learning codes. Could anyone guide with their expertise?

Comment: Welcome to the world of jupyterhub and stack overflow! When asking a question like this, you'll need to be much more specific going forward. There are a ton of different ways to set up jupyterhub servers, so in order to help, we need to know details about your setup, references to docs you're following, and most importantly what you've tried and where you're stuck. See [ask]. Ideally, try to create a [mre]. I think you're probably using The Littlest Jupyterhub (check it out if not) - the docs on authenticators are here: https://tljh.jupyter.org/en/latest/topic/authenticator-configuration.html

Comment: Another good place to get help is the [JupyterHub forum on discourse](https://discourse.jupyter.org/c/jupyterhub/tljh/13). Lots of jupyter experts hang out there and you'll find lots of existing, similar questions that might help you get set up.